What happens if the US President-elect is sent to prison before assuming power?
This is a question about the period between November 5 and January 20 in an election year.
If a presidential candidate wins the election but is sent to prison on November 6, say, would they stay in prison until they become president on January 20? Or is there some constitutional right to be released before January 20?
Edit I am really interested in the case where the elected candidate is not the sitting president. So the question of self pardon does not arise during this period, nor does the problem of serving while in prison.

Nothing we can do but speculate it has never been a possibility in the past and even now even if Trump is convicted of one of the criminal charges he is facing that he will get prison time.

why are there close votes and downvotes? a similar question has been asked in the past and was well-received: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/can-a-united-states-president-issue-a-self-pardon?noredirect=1&lq=1

@whoisit The linked question is not a duplicate. The power to self-pardon doesn't address what is happened is someone is elected and not pardoned, which is a real possibility at this point (particularly in the case of the two pending state law criminal prosecutions against Trump which carry presumptive sentences long enough to keep him incarcerated for at least part of his term of office). But it is a question that has some uncertainty in the answer, although there isn't an outright bar on interpreting constitutional law or answering about something with an uncertain answer.

The assumption that a sitting President would be released on January 20 is not at all a foregone conclusion.

@ohwilleke I didn't say it's a duplicate. Just saying that this question is not unique in its speculative nature

@whoisit: it's more speculative than the other/older Q. Even whether  the POTUS can pardon himself (or not) is undecided. (But at least one can point to papers and legal experts disagreeing on that.) This Q asks to take that one step further and predict possible scenarios from that. Which is even less discussed in sources. And it's also taking as a given that POTUS can pardon himself and asks us to spell out the details how that will play out exactly.

@whoisit For the simple reason that not every question that should be closed gets closed.

For what it's worth, while this has thankfully not yet been the case for a President-Elect, it actually has been the case for Presidential candidates in the past, as well as candidates for lower political offices. The most famous example is probably Eugene Debs, who ran for President of the U.S. from prison on the Socialist Party ticket in 1920. In the state where I live, there was a guy who continued his run for state Senate from jail, after having been arrested for murdering his opponent, who was the incumbent for that office. (He lost.)

@reirab Not sure if that really qualifies as that was the 5th time he had run for president and he had never gotten any electoral college votes. Not to mention he was in jail for protesting an anti free speech measure that made it treason to condemn the war/military things during WW1 and what he was jailed for is different then current issues. Debs v. United States (1919)

@JoeW Yeah, the sedition charges were definitely bogus and blatantly political (and the law used to level those charges has since been overturned as unconstitutional.) I was just pointing out that people have actually run for office from prison, not suggesting that particular one had any reasonable chance of winning or that the charges against him were fair.

Who knows? This hypothetically might be enough to kick off a Civil War ala the movie of the same name that's recently come out.

Related from the NYT "What sentencing could look like if Trump is found guilty" https://www.nytimes.com/2024/04/18/opinion/donald-trump-trial-prison.html

@ouflak Ross Douthat makes a pretty convincing case that it wouldn't start a civil war, in part, because too many people are lazy and comfortable. https://www.nytimes.com/2024/04/17/opinion/trump-civil-war.html

We will find out on November 26th

This is a question that has never come up so we don't know for sure. If we are lucky, we may never have to find out, because election results and criminal trial results will reach some permutation that prevents this question from arising.
But, until someone elected to be President takes office (if he is not the incumbent), the answer is easy. He stays in prison. If you are in prison for a crime, neither federal law nor state law provides that you are entitled to be released because you have been elected President.
After January 20, it would present something of a constitutional crisis not contemplated when the U.S. Constitution was drafted, because they couldn't imagine their electors choosing someone convicted of a felony, and imminently about to be incarcerated for it, being elected in the first place.
No one in the federal government has the power to pardon someone or commute the sentence of someone sentenced to prison for a state crime.
While it has never been tested historically and there is scholarly disagreement on the point, the majority view among legal scholars and professionals is that the President does not have the power to pardon or commute his own federal criminal conviction or sentence. See also here and here and here for other discussions on Politics.SE and Law.SE of that question.
The most obvious possibilities, after January 20, would be that the President would carry out his duties from prison, or would be impeached, or would be deemed disabled under the 25th Amendment allowing his Vice President to take over for the duration of his incarceration.

There is nothing in the page you linked to that shows that "the majority view among legal scholars and professionals is that the President does not have the power to pardon or commute his own federal criminal conviction or sentence."

@user76284 It is the position taken by the Department of Justice, it is the position backed by historical practice, and while legal scholars don't speak with on voice (and many have said nothing) it is the more common view of those who have really analyzed it.

There is no crisis. The constitution is clear. He becomes President on the twentieth and exits prison and assumes his office. The founding fathers did in fact imagine this scenario; special verbiage was required for congressmen but none for the president because he simply has the authority to order his own release (while in office).

@Joshua Do you have any references for your claim? The president only has authority over the executive branch of the federal government, so he could not issue orders to a state governor.

@Joshua There is no authority for that proposition.

@Joshua: It is conceivable (but wildly unprecedented and very questionable) that the President could issue an executive order to the Bureau of Prisons, commuting, suspending, or otherwise interfering with his own federal custodial sentence. But the actual scenario we are talking about, in practice, would be Trump getting convicted in New York, and given a state custodial sentence. There is no legal mechanism empowering the President to order New York's prison system around.

@Kevin: Ah; I missed that part of the context and reasoned over federal prison.

The Supremacy Clause, as it has been interpreted, would not seem to allow an active President to be a ward of any state.  It's almost unfathomable that SCOTUS would see it any other way.  Just think about it "congratulations on your post Mr. Lincoln, but South Carolina demands that you surrender yourself to serve a jail sentence for the crime of... we'll think of something.  You are welcome to continue exercising the powers of your office by correspondence.  We'll be sure to accommodate it."  The notion is quite absurd.  And SCOTUS is no friend of the absurd.

@RadicallyReasonable SCOTUS is very much a friend of the absurd. And, this will be one of the first of no doubt many constitutional crises presenting issues of first impression in the Trump Administration.

I knew you'd nitpick that particular claim.  SCOTUS may err on the side of being unreasonable, when they believe that's where the law lies.  But they don't push it to the absurd extremes.

@RadicallyReasonable Justice Scalia was willing to execute someone who was wrongfully convicted of murder because they procedurally exhausted their habeas corpus rights, even if the murder victim showed up in court before him. There are some pretty absurd extremes that it has supported.

That's sound's like a rhetoric produced in jest to emphasize the point of the importance of procedure.  But when it comes down to actually ruling, they consider all priorities with due, or nearly-due, proportionality.

@RadicallyReasonable Scalia was dead serious and it remains a point of contention in U.S. Constitutional law and habeas corpus law today. There are numerous law review articles on the topic. Your charitable view of how SCOTUS makes decisions is sadly mistaken.

We can agree to disagree on how extreme SCOTUS acts when it comes to the edge cases of the law. But it's not an edge case.  Congressional intent is sufficient for the Supremacy Clause preemption of state laws. And given that Congress has made it mandatory for Presidents to be under Secret Service's protection and that the Secret Service has to allow the President maximum capacity to exercise their power while remaining protected, it preempts any state's need to demonstrate that they are serious about procedural state crimes, especially those already known before an election.

@RadicallyReasonable The Supremacy Clause argument is not really a strong one. It would be laughable if the ultraconservative partially Trump appointed SCOTUS weren't in office and hadn't already butchered previous decisions like Trump v. Anderson and the Presidential immunity decision.

It's an entirely political opinion.  And, as I already pointed out, if this was the case, Presidents would be de facto removed from power, by states seeking to remove them from power, a long time ago.  All it would take would be a trumped up state charge.  The fact that it has never happened is a strong indication that the Supremacy Clause is not all that weak.

@RadicallyReasonable A more useful analogy would be the precedents (legal or just historical) of how member of Congress charged and convicted of state law crimes are handled.

I am not sure that it would be more useful.  But it would not be irrelevant.  The magnitude of the impact of disenfranchising the entirety of the United States makes it proportionately more severe.  So it's still almost certainly not going to happen.

There's several moving parts to explore.
Swearing in
The President can take the oath of office anywhere. Lyndon Johnson was sworn in on Air Force One at Love Field in Dallas after JFK was pronounced dead.

Sentencing
It's unlikely a court would send a President-elect to jail. It's not unreasonable to assume a court would suspend the sentence to allow the sitting President to run the country. Eventually the convicted President would no longer be in office and could serve their sentence after their term ended.
More likely the President-elect will have been sentenced before the election if they are to be in jail during the election and/or sitting in jail come Jan 20.
Congress
The incoming President will also likely have a Congress that has a majority of their party in charge. Expect this Congress to pass resolutions calling for the freedom of the new President. Expect also There will be tremendous political pressure on whatever court has jurisdiction over the new President.
The Courts
As ohwilleke noted, it's unclear if a sitting President can issue a pardon on their own behalf. I am going to assume the answer is in the negative. Regardless, that question would have to be sorted out by courts later.
Most likely, there will be legal motions already filed with the relevant state and/or Federal courts, and these motions will focus narrowly on having the President released from prison solely for the sake of running the country. It's going to be a lot easier to get a President released from jail than it will be in trying to overturn the conviction.
As we've seen on other issues, issues related to the Presidency tend to get expedient hearings and/or action. Expect petitions for emergency hearings to be granted, especially if lower level courts deny the motions to release the new President.
The determined state
The worst case scenario here is you have a state-level conviction and that state has elected officials who are determined to keep the new President behind bars. As others have mentioned, the President cannot pardon state convictions, so if prosecutors and courts are aligned against the new President it would mean that the legal process would have to wind through state courts. They could keep a sitting President locked up (in theory) for the entire time by keeping the case tied up in state courts. Federal courts would be less likely to get involved as long as there were no clear legal problems, just lots of legal maneuvering.
It's not impossible that a state that determined to enforce their sentence keeps the President locked up for the entirety of their term.
Presidential Prison
The prison would have to make some accommodations for the President. After all, it would look bad for any prison to have a President injured or killed under their roof. It's not unreasonable to assume they would either house arrest the President, or put them in a minimum security facility. That would afford some room for the Secret Service to assign a detail to protect them.

Not sure that I'd agree that federal courts are less likely to get involved. Given the nature of the circumstance, I would not be surprised to see a federal appellate court order immediate release pending the appeals actually working their way through federal appellate courts, likely up to (and possibly directly to) the Supreme Court to decide the question of if a state can even imprison the President in the first place. I don't think SCOTUS would wait for a circuit split to take such a case. Also worth remembering the Supremacy Clause. Anything that contradicted a federal law would be out.

And that's before considering that Congress could just pass a law that says, "No state may detain or imprison the President or Acting President of the United States" and that would end it.

@reirab: One possibility, though it would certainly be an unholy mess if it happened, would be for the courts to say "The 25th Amendment explicitly delegates the power to determine Presidential Inability to the political branches, so we can't rule on it. If the President says he is unable to govern from prison, we can't decide that question, and he must instead avail himself of the remedy in section 3 of the 25th Amendment." Obviously, Trump will not do that, so it's a bit of a catch-22.

@reirab There's too many variables there. If Trump is convicted in DC, the chances the court rushes it and rules in Trump's favor are low. DC Circuit won't be friendly territory either. Miami might be faster. But Fed courts don't have any jurisdiction over state courts initially. You need the trial, conviction and then appeals first.

@Machavity I agree that there are a lot of variables, but it's just the "federal courts would be less likely to get involved" part that I don't think is at all clear. As far as jurisdiction, if the question is whether the federal Constitution and/or federal law allow the President to be held in jail, I doubt that a conviction would first be necessary (as then the question would be moot anyway.) If the question is whether the President can be held in prison after conviction, then it's already after conviction by definition. As far as courts slow-walking a case, SCOTUS could handle that.

@Kevin If the President actually invoked the 25th Amendment, all they have to do to "un-invoke" it is send a letter to the President Pro Tem of the Senate and Speaker of the House, at which point they are immediately President again. I agree that courts would be unlikely to take a case with respect to the 25th Amendment, though, as it specifically delegates any required decisions to the President, Vice President, certain executive officials, and Congress.

@Kevin Even if the Vice President and a majority of the designated executive officers agreed that the President was unfit to serve, 2/3 of each house of Congress would have to agree if the President themselves disputed it. If 2/3 of both houses did not vote the President unfit for duty within 21 days (or a bit more if Congress was not already in session,) then the President would resume the duties of President. So it takes VP + majority of designated executive officials + 2/3 of Senate + 2/3 of the House to actually remove the President from duty without the President's consent.

I don’t think he is formally president-elect until after the electoral college vote on December 17.

House arrest == "White House arrest"?

@Barmar More or less. Or (if we're talking Trump) possibly being confined to Mar-a-lago.

@reirab: The argument, such as it is, would be that the President has the power to remediate his own inability under Section 3, and therefore it's none of the judiciary's business, regardless of whether he chooses to exercise that power or not. I'm skeptical, but it is an argument that could be made.

@Machavity Though I'd really like to see a state try to enforce that... I have a feeling the Secret Service would have some choice words for anyone who attempted to show up to enforce it. Something along the lines of "Freeze! Drop your weapons! You're under arrest!"

@Kevin Right, but that would only apply if the President declared himself unfit (or else VP + half of designated executive officials did so) and then for some reason sued to get his power back instead of just sending a letter to the Pres Pro Tem and the Speaker, which is all it takes for the President to get their power back.

@reirab: That is not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about a lawsuit for release from prison, not a lawsuit to regain his powers and duties. The idea is that he hasn't even invoked the 25th, but he could, so it's not the court's problem.

@Kevin I'm not sure how the 25th would be relevant to that at all. Those seem like very orthogonal concerns, as the 25th has nothing to do with being in prison or not. Actually invoking the 25th is a political question for sure, but detaining/imprisoning the President  (or anyone else for that matter) isn't. Even if there were some reason why invoking the 25th mattered, though, the President could simply invoke and then revoke it to dispense with such a matter.

@reirab: I already explained why the 25th would be relevant upthread. The idea is that it would undercut the President's "I can't govern from prison" argument (because, the argument goes, if you can't govern, then you're not supposed to go to court to remedy that problem).

@Kevin the 25th amendment provides w mechanism for the president to relinquish power temporarily and for the VP and cabinet to do it on his behalf.  None of this implies anything about how to remedy any given cause of an inability to govern.  For example, if the inability to govern were caused by a medical condition, you wouldn't say "you're not supposed to go to a doctor to remedy that problem."

In the case of Trump, the self-pardon question is moot because he was convicted of state crimes, not federal.

There's nothing in the US Constitution that prevents a prisoner from serving as a President. There's no requirement for a President to be in any specific location to be performing their duties.
Likelihood of that ever happening is pretty low though. If convicted of Federal crimes, the President will then obviously pardon and release themselves. If convicted of a State crime - it may be a bit more complicated, but the likelihood of any serious jail time for Trump in the New York case is probably not very high.

The President can't pardon himself, and furthermore can't pardon state law crimes.

@ohwilleke can't pardon himself - source please? I don't think that has ever been established, and with the current very friendly scotus seems unlikely to me

I've provided some links in my answer. Honestly, I don't believe that even the current U.S. Supreme Court would uphold an attempt by Trump to pardon himself of a federal crime (and certainly wouldn't allow him to pardon himself from a state crime).

I am really interested in the case where the elected candidate is not the sitting president.

@ohwilleke you don't? Based on what? The links that you provided don't say what you claim they say. You said the president can't pardon himself, none of your links says that.

That may be a problem, in Georgia AFAICT there's no such process.

@littleadv I guess the state legislature could pass a new state law allowing pardons?

@Simd It would take a state constitutional amendment.

@ohwilleke Interesting. So the question is if SCOTUS could release him before he is sworn in on January 20.

@Simd SCOTUS couldn't release him for any cognizable reason at that point, unless the underlying conviction was invalid for some reason arising under federal law not particular to the Presidency (e.g. if evidence was obtained in an illegal search and that impact was not harmless error).

@ohwilleke Your links show no such thing.

There's nothing in the constitution about POTUS being indicted, but DOJ policy is that they won't indict a sitting president due to the impact it would have on him performing his duties. Surely the impact of being in prison would be even worse.
